# How to set callbacks for updating FullCalendar Event objects in backend

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, backbone.js-collections

I'd like to add MongoDB / CouchDB as a backend for Fullcalendar. However I need to know when the event has been changed on the client side so I can trigger an update in the backend. Likewise I would need to set a delete callback that would be triggered once the event object was deleted on the client side.

Should the changes fail to propagate to the backend (connection or concurrency issues), the client side should revert to the oldest change saved in the backend.

From what I see about the updateEvent function it's at the view/GUI level and it's about updating/redrawing the View corresponding to the event. Can you please confirm this as well?

**UPDATE**: In essence I would like to add support in FullCalendar for object collections, collections such as those found in BackboneJS or AngularJS libraries.

Comment: Fullcalendar functions to update/delete etc refers to the rendered events already in view. What you need to do send updated data do server side store it in your noSQL DB, Refresh the calendar to fetch all events again. This will update your calendar and your events with the new data.

Another way is if you don´t want to refresh all calendar events everytime you do an update or delete, you can simulate in client side by giving each event a specific ID and with it tell Fullcalendar to update/delete that specific event client side. Server side do the 1st procedure without refreshing calendar.

Comment: Having to refresh the whole page does not feel right for me right now. I'll take the client side advice for now.

Comment: I agree with you but if you have a limited number of records to display, you will not feel the calendar go slower by doing a full refresh...